# Диофантово уравнение в четности или нечетности чисел?

Tags: математика, случайные-числа, криптография, mathematica

Я хочу разобраться с формулами решения диофантовых уравнений. Недавно я наткнулся на старую статью посвященная понятиям теории эллиптических кривых. Меня заинтересовал раздел **["МЕТОД СЕКУЩИХ ДИОФАНТА"](http://window.edu.ru/resource/758/20758/files/9710_138.pdf).**

http://window.edu.ru/resource/758/20758/files/9710_138.pdf

если  `y^2 = x^3 + ax + b` это формула кривой которое образует точки `G(x, y)`

При сложение координат мы получаем новую точку
[Jacobian curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_curve)

а так же новую точку можно получить и при скалярном умножение точек на порядковый номер *(то есть на закрытый ключ)*

используя [онлайн генератор](https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/modk-add.html) я построил простенькую кривую

**Параметры кривой:**

```
y^2 = x^3 + ax + b % p
p = 897
a = 0; b = 8
```

**Базовая точка**
**G(x) = 268
G(y) = 741**

У меня возник вопрос допустим у меня есть новая точка `(100, 396)` мне неизвестен закрытый ключ к нему и мне неизвестно является ли закрытый ключ четным или нечетным числом.
Можно ли применяя формулы диофантовых уравнений определить является ли закрытый ключ четным или нечетным числом для новой точки `(100, 396)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в статье о диофантовых уравнениях, на которую вы привели ссылку, явным образом сказано

> В настоящее время неизвестно никакой общей процедуры для нахождения всех рациональных решений уравнения y2 = x3 + ax2 + bx + c.

Во-вторых, решение диофантового уравнения не даёт ответ на ваш вопрос - найти множитель `n` такой, что `P = nG`.

В-третьих, и в главных, статья о диофантовых уравнениях ищет рациональные точки над E, то есть точки с координатами в `Q` - поле рациональных чисел. У вас же кривая над полем вычетов по модулю простого числа.

Принципиальная разница заключается в том, что квадратный корень в `Q` извлекается крайне редко - вероятность случайно выбрать число `m/n` которое является квадратом рационального числа, стремится к нулю по мере роста `n`. Поэтому уравнение `y^2 = ax^3 + bx + c` в `Q` решить крайне нетривиально.

Но в полях вычетов по модулю `p` половина элементов имеет корень (доказательство смотрите, например, в книге [Блейхут Р. Теория и практика кодов, контролирующих ошибки, теорема 4.6.15 на странице 105](https://scask.ru/h_book_tpc.php?id=26)). Поэтому уравнение `y^2 = ax^3 + bx + c` решается практически для любого `x`, и никакие методы решения диофантовых уравнений не требуются.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос - нет, нельзя. Методы решения диофантовых уравнений не применимы для ответа на вопрос *является ли чётным число `n` из уравнения `P = nG`*